# I have a list of around 150 objects and when i map it only around 20 load | React Native

Tags: react-native, listview, expo, react-native-flatlist

Assume the fetch returns an object of 150 items, of this 150 items only 20 are rendered as components. I've tried FlatList, LargeList and have watched multiple youtube videos and can't seem to get it to work.

I run this on the Expo Dev app, and when I scroll to the bottom of the list, no more load. Only about 20 cards are rendered.

This is what the end of the screen looks like, I try scroll down more and no more load.

Screen shot when scrolling to the bottom:
[image: screen shot of app]

Screen shot after scrolling to the bottom:
[image: screen shot of app 2]

This is the code for my home screen:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, ScrollView, Alert, ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import HeaderTabs from '../components/HeaderTabs';
import Screen from '../components/Screen'
import Categories from '../components/Categories'
import SearchBar from '../components/SearchBar'
import ServiceItem from "../components/ServiceItem";
import tailwind from 'tailwind-react-native-classnames';
import { localServices } from '../data/localServices';
import colors from '../configs/colors'

const YELP_API_KEY = "RF2K7bL57gPbve8oBSiX23GYdCVxIl-KedmS-lyEafEZKNIn6DgsN6j88JvHolhiT4LH-VxT2NvDwgzl9yCTW-5REbbu3Cl5vwqCNUtGhnzzScPinQciOvs6PVBtY3Yx";

const HomeScreen = () => {
    const [serviceData, setServiceData] = useState(localServices)
    const [city, setCity] = useState("San Francisco")
    const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState("Delivery");
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

    const getServicesFromYelp = () => {
        const yelpUrl = `https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=Home+Services&location=${city}`;

        const apiOptions = {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${YELP_API_KEY}`,
            },
        };
        setLoading(true)
        return fetch(yelpUrl, apiOptions)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((json) => {
                    setLoading(false)
                    if(json.error) return Alert.alert('Sorry', json.error.description);
                    setServiceData(
                        json?.businesses?.filter((business) =>
                            // business.transactions.includes(activeTab.toLowerCase())
                            business
                            // city.includes(business.location.city)
                        )
                    )
                }
            );
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getServicesFromYelp();
    }, [city, activeTab]);


    return (
        <Screen style={tailwind`bg-white flex-1`}>
            <HeaderTabs activeTab={activeTab} setActiveTab={setActiveTab} />
            <SearchBar setCity={setCity} city={city} />
            <ScrollView style={tailwind`flex-1`} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
                <Categories />
                {loading && <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={colors.primary} style={tailwind`mt-2 mb-6`} />}
                <ServiceItem serviceData={serviceData} />
            </ScrollView>
        </Screen>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})

export default HomeScreen;
```

This is the code for the individual components:

ServiceItem.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import ServiceItemCard from "./ServiceItemCard";

const ServiceItem = ({ serviceData }) => {
    return (
        <View>
            {serviceData?.map((item, index) => (
                <ServiceItemCard key={index} item={item} />
            ))}
        </View>
    );
}

export default ServiceItem;
```

ServiceItemCard.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Image, Text, TouchableOpacity, View, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import tailwind from 'tailwind-react-native-classnames';
import { Entypo } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';


const ServiceItemCard = ({ item }) => {
    const [loved, setLoved] = useState(false)

    return (
        <View style={tailwind`mx-4 mb-4`}>
            <Image
                source={{ uri: item.image_url ? item.image_url : null}}
                style={tailwind`w-full h-48 rounded-lg`}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity style={tailwind`absolute top-2 right-2`} onPress={() => setLoved(e => !e)}>
                <Entypo name={`${loved ? 'heart' : 'heart-outlined'}`} size={28} color="#fff" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View style={tailwind`flex-row items-center mt-1`}>
                <View style={tailwind`flex-grow`}>
                    <Text style={tailwind`font-bold text-lg`} numberOfLines={1}>{item.name}</Text>
                    <View style={tailwind`flex-row items-center`}>
                        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="clock-time-four" size={13} color="#06C167" />
                        <Text style={tailwind`text-xs text-gray-700`}> 20-30 • min • {item.price}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={tailwind`w-8 h-8 justify-center items-center bg-gray-100 rounded-full`}>
                    <Text style={tailwind`text-gray-600 text-xs`}>{item.rating}</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

export default ServiceItemCard;
```

I tried using FlatList, LargeList and messing around with infinite scrolling

Comment: can you add current screenshot and expected result into question?

Comment: @niran Added screen shots of current results, in total around 20 of the 150 items are rendered from the list

Comment: Where is the ```FlatList``` declaration? I just see the import, but didn't see it declaration. Am I missing something?? Further information, FlatList's lazy loading, so it can be more performant if you have a huge list, also It much more suitable instead using the ```map``` approach. Another great resource can be seen https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15990

Comment: @LanceNieva Where is the FlatList code